# Parse XML in List<CustomClass> with Linq query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

my problem is how to implement a linq query that parse from an XML file to a List class
Here is the custom class:

**CustomClass.cs**

```
public class ListItem
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int minLevel;
    public int minAttr1;
    public int minAttr2;
    public float damage;
    public float additionalDmg;
    public string additionalDmgType;
    public float range;
    public float cost;

    public ListItem(
        int _id,
        string _name,
        int _minLevel,
        int _minAttr1,
        int _minAttr2,
        float _damage,
        float _additionalDmg,
        string _additionalDmgType,
        float _range,
        float _cost)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
        minLevel = _minLevel;
        minAttr1 = _minAttr1;
        minAttr2 = _minAttr2;
        damage = _damage;
        additionalDmg = _additionalDmg;
        additionalDmgType = _additionalDmgType;
        range = _range;
        cost = _cost;
    }
}
```

This is an example of the xml file that I have:

**File.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weapons>
  <Weapon id="0">
    <Name>spada</Name>
    <MinLevel>1</MinLevel>
    <MinAttr1>10</MinAttr1>
    <MinAttr2>5</MinAttr2>
    <Damage>100</Damage>
    <AdditionalDmg>10</AdditionalDmg>
    <AdditionalDmgType>Electric</AdditionalDmgType>
    <Range>1</Range>
    <Cost>1000</Cost>
  </Weapon>
  <Weapon id="1">
    <Name>spada2</Name>
    <MinLevel>1</MinLevel>
    <MinAttr1>10</MinAttr1>
    <MinAttr2>5</MinAttr2>
    <Damage>100</Damage>
    <AdditionalDmg>10</AdditionalDmg>
    <AdditionalDmgType>Electric</AdditionalDmgType>
    <Range>1</Range>
    <Cost>1000</Cost>
  </Weapon>
</Weapons>
```

This is Importer class that need the linq query for parsing:

**Importer.cs**

```
class Importer
    {
        public void ImportXML()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(sr);
                sr.Close();

                //Miss here linq query 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My try (but "data" variable still null):**

```
 var data = from item in xml.Elements("weapon")
                       select new
                       {
                           name = item.Element("Name").Value,
                           minLevel = item.Element("MinLevel").Value
                       };
            foreach (var p in data)
            Debug.WriteLine(p.ToString());
```

Comment: Why not use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Add XML Serialization with appropriate attributes at each field.

Comment: The only problem with you code is the tags are upper/lower case sensitive.  The xml has a capital 'W" in Weapon while the c# code has lowercase 'w' in weapon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four issues:

1. The `<Weapon>` elements are children of the `<Weapons>` root element not the overall document.
2. XML is case sensitive, so when searching for elements or attributes by name you need to match the case exactly.  Thus `xml.Root.Elements("weapon")` should be `xml.Root.Elements("Weapon")`.
3. When converting an `XElement` value to a different type, say `int`, you should use [explicit casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This handles internationalization correctly.  And do the same for [`XAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154727%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) conversions.
4. "id" is an attribute, so use [`XElement.Attribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access it.

Thus:

```
        var data = from item in xml.Root.Elements("Weapon")
                   select new
                   {
                       name = (string)item.Element("Name"),
                       minLevel = (int)item.Element("MinLevel"),
                       id = (int)item.Attribute("id")
                   };
```

Comment: Can help me for the retrieving of "id" attribute in Weapon element too?

Answer (score 1):

The `Elements` children returns only direct children of a `XContainer`, so in your case `xml.Elements("weapon")` return the empty collection because there isn't any `weapon` element at the root of XML.

You should use

```
var data = from item in xml.Root.Elements("Weapon")
           select new {
               name = item.Element("Name").Value,
               minLevel = item.Element("MinLevel").Value
           };
```

Comment: Your answer are good but the dbc one are more precisly but many thanks!